# How to animate opacity in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: animation, mobile, xamarin, cross-platform, xamarin.forms

I wonder how to Animate opacity of elements visible on screen. For example for Entry I got to this:

```
this.Animate("", d =>
{
   Debug.WriteLine("anim:" + d);
   Username.Opacity = (AnimationTime - d) / AnimationTime;
}, 0, AnimationTime);
```

but I wonder if there is easier way. Unfortunately Animate method is poorly documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the FadeTo extension method :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#fading

There are other animations that can be applied too :-

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple

Answer (score 7):

Use the YourLabel.FadeTo() method. For example, if you define the opacity to 0 starting the app,

```
await MyLabel.FadeTo (1, 2000, Easing.Linear);
```

means : the animation (changing opacity here) will last for 2000 ms linearly passing from 0 to 1.