# Display custom popup as fully opaque like Page.DisplayAlert()

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using rg popups to add popup and an entry field into my app however the end result is partially transparent and I can see the underlying controls. I want it to be like the DisplayAlert where they cant see below it. I am using zing to scan barcode then place a popup with a qty field in it.

https://github.com/rotorgames/Rg.Plugins.Popup/tree/master/src/Demo/Demo/Pages

```
<pages:PopupPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
                  xmlns:animations="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Animations;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"             
                  xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:Rg.Plugins.Popup.Pages;assembly=Rg.Plugins.Popup"       
             x:Class="FuelStockApp.Views.PopupInputBox">
    <pages:PopupPage.Animation>
        <animations:ScaleAnimation 
      PositionIn="Center"
      PositionOut="Center"
      ScaleIn="1.2"
      ScaleOut="0.8"
      DurationIn="400"
      DurationOut="300"
      EasingIn="SinOut"
      EasingOut="SinIn"
      HasBackgroundAnimation="True"/>
        </pages:PopupPage.Animation>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  Padding="20, 20, 20, 20">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0, 10, 0, 0">
            <StackLayout>


                <Entry 
                   HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"      
                   Placeholder="Please Enter Qty:" 
                   Keyboard="Numeric"
                       x:Name="txtMessage"
                   TextColor="Gray"></Entry>

                <Button x:Name="btnClose" Text="Ok"  Clicked="OnClose"></Button>

            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</pages:PopupPage>
```

Code for the Button click scan.

```
private async void BtnTestScan_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var scanPage = new ZXingScannerPage();
    scanPage.ToggleTorch();
    scanPage.IsScanning = true;
    // Navigate to our scanner page
    await Navigation.PushAsync(scanPage);


    scanPage.OnScanResult += (result) =>
    {
            // Stop scanning
            scanPage.IsScanning = false;


             // Pop the page and show the result
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
            {

                await Navigation.PopAsync();

    BomComponentData getInfo = await database.GetBomByBarCode(result.Text);

                var popup = new FuelStockApp.Views.PopupInputBox("You scanned the item "+ getInfo.Name + "You need to pick " +getInfo.Quantity.ToString());

                await Rg.Plugins.Popup.Services.PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(popup);

            });
        };
 }
```

[image]

This is my code behind as their is some animiation there to deal with opactity that may be the issue.

```
public partial class PopupInputBox : PopupPage
{
    public PopupInputBox(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        txtMessage.Text = message;
    }

    private async void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();
    }

    protected override Task OnAppearingAnimationEndAsync()
    {
        return Content.FadeTo(0.5);
    }

    protected override Task OnDisappearingAnimationBeginAsync()
    {
        return Content.FadeTo(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using [FadeTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.viewextensions.fadeto?view=xamarin-forms) incorrectly.

`Content.FadeTo(0.5)` will set the transparency to .5 which creates that partially transparent effect you see. I believe what you want is something more like `Content.FadeTo(1, 500)` which will cause the `View` to appear as fully opaque after 500ms (a half second).

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27985759/how-to-animate-opacity-in-xamarin-forms) to a related question might help as well.